# EFCode First: Deleting a Value Object with Two Entity Associations

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am having trouble deleting a Value Object from my database because it has two relationships with different Entities, it just sets one foreign key to null which throws.  Here is my domain:

```
public class Product : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductQuantity> ProductQuantities { get; set; }
}

public class Project: IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SpecConnect { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductQuantity> ProductQuantitys { get; set; }
}

public class ProductQuantity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code to Delete a ProductQuantity off the Project:

```
var product = _productRepository.GetById(id);
var project = _projectRepository.GetById(projectId);
var productQuantity = project.ProductQuantitys.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Product == product);

project.ProductQuantitys.Remove(productQuantity);
```

Thank you for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough. You must remove the object from both `Product` and `Project` and after that you must delete it by calling `context.ProductQuantities.Remove(...)`

Removing object from those collections will only delete independent association you defined. It leads to setting the FK in database to null but not to deleting the related object.

Btw. value object doesn't have Id / key. Value object in EF is a complex type.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your feedback.  You are right, I should not have an Id in my ProductQuantity object.  context.ProductQuantities.Remove will not work since this object is not an entity. I think I just have my domain model wrong?  I need to have a ProductQuantity because I also have an int of Quantity in the object so it is not just an association between project and product. When I remove the Id and rebuild the database I get an error that a key is not set, however I also get an error when I create a map object to set the HasKey property to Product and Project? Thoughts on the proper way.